# Appended images won't have hover effects

Tags: jquery, hover, append

So I just noticed this. Basically my code appends a bunch of images to the end when the window is resized, so that you have a continuous line of images, rather than an abrupt end that would mess with design. So I might add 4 images, or 2, depending on the screen size.

```
function imageNumber() { 

    $('#images br').remove();
    $('.appended').remove();

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 


    var numberOfImages = $("#images img").length;
    var numberOfImagesPerRow = Math.ceil(windowWidth / imageWidth);

    $('#images img:nth-child('+numberOfImagesPerRow+'n)').after('<br />')
    $('#images br:last-child').remove();

    var nuLineBreaks = $('br').length + 1;

    if(numberOfImages % numberOfImagesPerRow != 0) {

         var numberOnRow = Math.round((1 - (numberOfImages/numberOfImagesPerRow % 1)) * numberOfImagesPerRow); 
         var number = 0;

         while(number <= numberOnRow) { 

            $('.i'+number).clone().appendTo($('#images')).attr('class', 'appended');
            ++number;

         }

    }

}
```

I noticed that the appended images aren't animated.

```
$('#images img').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'width' : '250px', 'height' : '250px'});
},
function() { 
    $(this).css({'width' : '200px', 'height' : '200px'});
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the images you're adding to the page don't have hover effects. This is because the event handler is only attached to the elements jQuery found at the time `hover()` was called. New elements (like those created by `clone()`) don't have any event handlers attached.

In your case, you might want to use `clone(true)`, which [tells jQuery to copy event handlers and data as well](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Another option would be to attach the hover event to the parent element (#images) using `on()`, and specify a selector to filter the child elements that should trigger the event, like so:

```
$("#images").on("mouseover", "img", function() {
    // mouseover code
}).on("mouseleave", "img", function() {
    // mouseleave code
});
```

In this case, since the event handler is attached to *#images*, it will be triggered no matter what `img` elements you end up adding to it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of jQuery do you have?  If 1.7 then look at the on method: http://api.jquery.com/on/  if earlier then look at live: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the guy below was a little more informative :3